# Add a row to each dataframe of the list containing mean values of certain rows

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames called my_list. Below is a sample of a dataframe in my_list.

```
> print(df1)    
       A          B         Names
1   0.8262825   0.734412    Baseline
2   1.0100000   0.734412    Sample1
3   0.8262825   0.734412    Sample2
4   1.0100000   0.734412    Sample3
5   0.8262825   0.734412    Sample4
6   1.0100000   0.734412    Sample5
7   0.8262825   0.734412    Sample6
8   1.0100000   0.734412    Sample7
9   0.8262825   0.734412    Sample8
10  1.0100000   0.734412    Sample9
11  0.8262825   0.734412    Sample10
12  1.0100000   NA          AASHTO
```

I would like to add a new row to every dataframe in my_list contain the mean values of columns A and B except the rows that have "Baseline" and "AASHTO" in column Names. (So only the mean of the rows with Sample1 to Sample10)

Finally I would like to set the Name column to the row names of each dataframe in my_list and remove the column Names from all dataframes in the list.

The expected result for each dataframe in my_list would be

```
                A          B         
Baseline    0.8262825   0.734412    
Sample1     1.0100000   0.734412    
Sample2     0.8262825   0.734412    
Sample3     1.0100000   0.734412    
Sample4     0.8262825   0.734412    
Sample5     1.0100000   0.734412    
Sample6     0.8262825   0.734412    
Sample7     1.0100000   0.734412    
Sample8     0.8262825   0.734412    
Sample9     1.0100000   0.734412    
Sample10    0.8262825   0.734412
Mean        0.8156500   0.734412
AASHTO      1.0100000   NA
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `lapply`, get the `colMeans` of columns 'A', 'B' excluding the rows where the 'Names' are 'Baseline' or 'AASHTO', then `rbind` with the original dataset

```
lst2 <-  lapply(lst1, function(x) {
   means <- colMeans(x[!x$Names %in% c("Baseline", "AASHTO"),
            c('A', 'B')], na.rm = TRUE)
        d1 <- rbind(x, data.frame(Names = "Mean", as.list(means)))
        row.names(d1) <- d1$Names
        d1[setdiff(names(d1), "Names")]
             })
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
            add_row(Names = 'Mean', 
              A = mean(.$A[!.$Names %in% c("Baseline", "AASHTO")], 
                     na.rm = TRUE),
              B = mean(.$B[!.$Names %in% c("Baseline", "AASHTO")], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
         `row.names<-`(., NULL) %>%
             column_to_rownames('Names'))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(structure(list(A = c(0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 
1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01), B = c(0.734412, 
0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 
0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, NA), Names = c("Baseline", "Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7", 
"Sample8", "Sample9", "Sample10", "AASHTO")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12")), structure(list(
    A = c(0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01, 
    0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01, 0.8262825, 1.01), B = c(0.734412, 
    0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 
    0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, 0.734412, NA), Names = c("Baseline", 
    "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", 
    "Sample7", "Sample8", "Sample9", "Sample10", "AASHTO")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12")))
```